# Latest sonar-application zip not deployed to codehaus repository

Tags: sonarqube, nexus

We have a situation where we need to customer the sonar zip created by the sonar-application maven project.  In the past we have done this by referencing the zip thru a maven dependency.  In this case many of the other sub-projects for sonar 3.5.1 have been deployed, to the CodeHaus Nexus repository, but not the sonar-application artifact.  In fact, it hasn't been deployed since version 1.4.x. I was hoping someone can tell me why this is.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed zip file is not uploaded as a maven artifact. It's available at http://dist.sonar.codehaus.org/